# Laplace transform - How to determine the initial conditions of the derivative functions

Tags: laplace-transform

I m trying to get the transfer function of this circuit. I do it essentially for fun. I clearly a newbie about Laplace's transformation. Nevertheless here is the circuit :

[image]

Here is the differential equation :

[image]

As you can see, I tried to use the Laplace's transform to get the expression of the transfer function Ic(s)/Vin(s) in the s-plane. But the Laplace transform depends on the initial conditions of the systems which seems clearly logical. Nevertheless I have some troubles to determine the value @ t = 0 of the derivative functions of ic(t) and Vin(t). Actually I would like to simulate a step reponse. If it is a step response I want to say in theory that Vin'(0) is equal to infinite. What about ic''(0) and ic'(0)... Is there a way to know what could be those values ?

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Comment: The definition of Transfer Function assumes zero initial conditions. See your textbook.

Comment: I think it would be better if you post your comment as an answer instead @DirceuRodriguesJr

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) I will try some simple applications to better understand !